# как к кнопке в телеграм боте прикрутить выполнение команды

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

есть код, не пойму как прикрутить выполнение команды, при нажатии на кнопку

```
import sqlite3
import config
import datetime
import telebot
from telebot import types

today = datetime.date.today()
tomorrow = today + datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
today = today.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
tomorrow = tomorrow.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

keyboard_markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
btn_today = types.KeyboardButton('today')
btn_tomorrow = types.KeyboardButton('tomorrow')
keyboard_markup.add(btn_today, btn_tomorrow)

@bot.message_handler(commands=["today"])
def add_user_handler(message):
    con = sqlite3.connect('schedule.db')
    cursor = con.cursor()
    sql = ("SELECT * FROM 'schedule' WHERE date=?")
    today_sql = (today,)
    cursor.execute(sql, today_sql)
    today_schedule = cursor.fetchone()
    clear_schedule = ''

    while today_schedule is not None:
        clear_schedule += ("text" + '\n' +
                           "text: " + str(today_schedule[0]) + '\n' +
                           "text: "+ str(today_schedule[1]) + '\n' +
                           "text: " + str(today_schedule[3]) + '\n' +
                           "text: " + str(today_schedule[4]) + '-' + (today_schedule[5]) + '\n' +
                           "text: " + str(today_schedule[6]))
        today_schedule = cursor.fetchone()

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, clear_schedule, reply_markup=keyboard_markup)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: как это реализовать на aiogram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

при нажатии на `types.KeyboardButton()` в чат от имени пользователя отправляется значение этой кнопки. бот выполняет команды через `/`, например `/start`, поэтому:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    keyboard_markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    btn_today = types.KeyboardButton('/today')
    btn_tomorrow = types.KeyboardButton('tomorrow')
    keyboard_markup.add(btn_today, btn_tomorrow)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'clear_schedule', reply_markup=keyboard_markup)


@bot.message_handler(commands=["today"])
def add_user_handler(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ну вот тебе и today')
```

либо отлавливать как текст:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def blabla(message):
    if message.text == 'tomorrow':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ну вот тебе и tomorrow')
```

Comment: Спасибо, в принципе подходит. а можно ли сделать так, что бы название кнопки не отправлялось в чат? что бы при нажатии на кнопку сразу показывался результат выполнения команды

Comment: в таком случае используйте https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/inline_keyboard_example.py

Answer (score 1):

Можешь поменять меседж хендлер так чтобы он работал только при определенном тексте. Вот пример:

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == "Оставить почту и отзыв").
```

Reply кнопка "Оставить почту и отзыв"